# Как создать мультиязычный сайт WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать мультиязычный сайт с помощью плагинов. Хочу добавить украинский язык.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие плагины как:

- [wpml](https://wpml.org/ru/) (платный)
- [polylang](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) (есть бесплатный вариант)

Таких плагинов очень много, попробуйте поискать в google.